# Addition incoming SMTP listen on port 2525 with Zimbra 8

Tags: smtp, port, zimbra

We use some service on Google Cloud, but they block out-going port 25 / 465 / 587, I need add a smtp port on our Zimbra server that listening on port 2525 for these service can send email.

My Zimbra version: 8.7.7

Search result only some guide for old Zimbra version.

Answer (score 3):

the only thing you need to do in version 8.7.7 is :
Search in /opt/zimbra/common/conf/master.cf.in for this line:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
```

and add that line above :

```
2525      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

Now your file will looks like that :

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
2525      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

Save the file and restart your zimbra :

```
$ su zimbra

$ zmmtactl restart
```

Comment: you could use postscreen as command name instead of smtpd to keep postscreen active on port 2525.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, postfix is used and based on https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Adding_additional_SMTP_listener_ports you still can do:

Search in /opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/master.cf.in for this line:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

To add an additional listener port of 2525, insert the the following after the above:

```
2525      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

Then, restart the MTA:

```
# su - zimbra
# zmmtactl stop
# zmmtactl start
```